# Generic decorator VS generic decorators' decorator

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, functional-programming

Here is my little snippet:

```
def genericDecorator(*decoArgs, **decoKwargs):
    """Accept arbitrary arguments, and use them to decorate functions.
    """
    def decoWrapper(func):
        def funcWrapper(*funcArgs, **funcKwargs):
            # You can do anything else you want here 
            print decoArgs, decoKwargs
            func(*funcArgs, **funcKwargs)
        return funcWrapper
    return decoWrapper

# Example:
@genericDecorator(42, 404, whatever = 1024)
def decoratedFunc(a, b, c, isAwesome = True):
    print a, b, c, isAwesome

decoratedFunc(1, 2, 3)
```

Output:

```
(42, 404) {'whatever': 1024}
1 2 3 True
```

The "generic" in the title and the variable name basically means two things:

- It can accept an arbitrary number of arguments.
- The function it decorates can accept an arbitrary number of arguments.

---

Some background information:

I've just learned what "decorators" are from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5399734) today. However, the author posted a bonus snippet "to make any decorator accept generically any argument", which defines a decorators' decorator.(Search for "Let’s practice: decorating a decorator" on that page, and you can find the snippet I mean.)

IMHO a decorators' decorator makes things unnecessarily complicated, because "Flat is better than nested". So I write my own snippet, and I want to know whether my approach is better than that author's. If not, why?

Thank you for reviewing.

Comment: Can you show a meaningful example of how this can be used?

Comment: **Lacks concrete context:** Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Having said that, yes, I agree a decorators' decorator makes things unnecessarily complicated. I see no use for it.